# friend function not printing out what it should

Tags: c++, oop, friend, friend-function

whenever I run the program, there is no output, the program just ends. Am i doing something wrong? I'm sure there's something i missed but i can't seem to figure it out.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Addr
{
public:
    Addr(int i = 0){
        total = i;
    }

void addNum(int num){
    total += num;
}

int getNum(){ 
    return total; }

friend int print(Addr& var);

private:
   int total;
};

int print(Addr& var){
    return var.total;
}

int main()
{
    Addr object1;
    object1.addNum(3);
    print(object1);

    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: If you expect something to print, you should use `cout`, for example: `cout<<print(object1);`.  Your code is running correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Your program behaves correctly. There is no output because you are not printing anything to the console in your program.

The `print` function merely returns the `total`.

If you wish to print the value to the console then you could for example change the definition as follows:

```
int print(Addr& var){
    cout << var.total << endl; // this prints to the console output
    return var.total;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with your code. The fact is that no print function is used. I have modified your main function.

```
int main()
{
    Addr object1;
    object1.addNum(3);

    cout<<print(object1);

    return 0;
}
```